# Exception being thrown for connect 4 algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, methods

So I keep running into a problem with my code for checking if there is a connect 4 vertically. Preface to my code: the board has 6 rows and 7 columns, the variable player1 holds the value of the character being used as a chip and playerID just holds the value of whoever gets the connect 4.

```
public int verticalWin() {
    int playerID = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < board[x].length; x++) {
        int count = 1;
        for (int y = board.length-2; y >= 0; y--) {
            if (board[y][x] == board[y+1][x]) {
                count++;
                if (count == 4) {
                    if (board[y][x] == player1) {
                        playerID = 1;
                    } else {
                        playerID = 2;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                count = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return playerID;
}
```

The problem I keep running into is that an exception `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6` keeps happening and I think it's in the first line, but I can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: *I think it's in the first line*: the stack trace tells you exactly what line throws that exception. Don't guess. Read the stack trace. Then use your debugger to step through the code step by step, and watch the values of the variables.

Comment: Well according to the stack trace it is the first line, but I'm saying I think because I can't find the bug.

Comment: The problem is x < board[x].length. If you increase x it will eventually go out of bounds. It doesnt make sense anyway because the first index is y. If all the rows are the same size you can just use board[0].length

Answer (score 0):

Some cleaner code

```
boolean isWinnerOnColumn(int playerID, int column) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < 6; row++) {
        count = (board[row][column] == playerID) ? (count + 1) : 0;
        if (count == 4){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public int verticalWin() {
     for (int column = 0; column < 7; column++) {

         if (isWinnerOnColumn(1, column) {
            return 1;
         }

         if (isWinnerOnColumn(2, column) {
            return 2;
         }
     }
     return 0; // no winner
}
```