# How to format into a board?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm making a game of connect 4 in Java and I'm curious how to format the board. I have a default constructor that when called will create the generic 6(rows)x7(columns) board.

```
    public Board(){
        int[][] defaultBoard = new int[6][7];
        for(int i = 0; i < defaultBoard.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < defaultBoard[i].length; j++){
                System.out.println("x");
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I edit the `println` so I create a perfect board? I was thinking about using `printf` but I'm not that familiar with it.

Comment: Try to define what are you trying to accomplish. Then write down some basic (or more detailed) idea of solution/algorithm which is supposed to do it. Then try to implement it. If you have *specific* problem which is stopping you from moving forward with your code post it.

Comment: Is everyone in your class consulting SO for guidance on how to implement Connect 4?  This is the second C4 question today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810891/exception-being-thrown-for-connect-4-algorithm/40811129#40811129

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for just a 6×7 grid representation instead of the 42×1 you currently have, I'd recommend changing that println to a print. i.e

```
for(int i=0; i<defaultBoard.length; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<defaultBoard[i].length; j++)
    {
        System.out.print("x");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```